# "make" fails when using pattern matching

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a generic make file so that I can compile my project independently of how many files I add to it and where I decide to put them in the project tree.

In my step by step approach I cam to this makefile which works fine.

```
CC=g++
OBJECTS=main.o board.o
VPATH=src:\
            src/board:\
            include/board:\
            build:\
            bin

boardG : main.o board.o
    $(CC) -o bin/boardG build/main.o build/board.o

main.o : main.cpp board.hpp
    $(CC) -c -I include $< -o build/$@

board.o : board.cpp board.hpp
    $(CC) -c -I include $< -o build/$@
```

This version will do the job just fine. See output below:

```
me@01:~/code/projects/boardG$ make
g++ -c -I include src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++ -c -I include src/board/board.cpp -o build/board.o
g++ -o bin/boardG build/main.o build/board.o
```

The problem here is that I will have to create one rule for each .cpp file. Which is precisely what I try to avoid. Hence I tried to adapt the version above using matching patterns like this:

```
CC=g++
OBJECTS=main.o board.o
VPATH=src:\
            src/board:\
            include/board:\
            build:\
            bin

boardG : main.o board.o
    $(CC) -o bin/boardG build/main.o build/board.o

%.o : %.cpp %.hpp
    $(CC) -c -I include $< -o build/$@
```

When I run make now I get the follwing output:

```
me@01:~/code/projects/boardG$ make
g++    -c -o main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:2:27: fatal error: board/board.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

My project has the follwing structure/files in it.

```
./bin/
./build/
./include/board/board.hpp
./src/main.cpp
./src/board/board.cpp
./makefile
```

I'm wondering why make would change the command when using pattern matching? Or, and probably more accurately, what am I doing wrong that makes make fail?

Comment: That is probably using the built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule since it can't find the `%.hpp` file to match your target. Disable those rules (`-r`) and you should see it fail differently. Running `make -d` may be useful in terms of showing you what make is trying to do when it finds your targets. (I'm not sure how VPATH plays with multiple pattern prerequisites in a single target.)

Comment: You have some rules that build files other than the files they promise to build (e.g. `build/board.o` instead of `board.o`), and another rule that plays along with this fiction, by claiming to need the files that are not built and then using the files that are. Naturally this breaks as soon as you try to generalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just avoid using `VPATH` when it comes to object files. What's happening is that make is actually using the built-in rule for `%.o` and not using your rule at all.

If you prefix all your objects with the directory, this should work:

```
CC=g++
OBJDIR = build
OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/board.o
VPATH = src:\
            src/board:\
            include/board:\

bin/boardG : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp %.hpp
    $(CC) -c -I include $< -o $@
```

---

Here is a [helpful resource](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/), which more or less exactly describes the problem you've run into.

Comment: It' worth noting that there's nothing wrong with using VPATH to find *object files* as such. The problem is that VPATH is no help in finding files that don't yet exist.

Comment: I'm unfortunately getting a new error now: "...No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'bin/boardG'...". Anyhow, the resource you provided is very interesting. Mainly [Paul’s Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) help a great deal. According to the [third one](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule3), targets should be build in the current directory, hence I'm making my life unnecessarily complicated it seems. I will put something together that respects that rule and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work now. % in the dependency will match the stem from the target. Thus, whilst compiling main.o, make assumes that the dependency is main.hpp whereas it actually is board.hpp. As a result it failed as main.hpp doesn't exist. I changed the dependency from %.hpp to board.hpp and it's working fine now. I now need a cleaner way to deal with the dependencies, as well as one allowing me not to break Paul's rule #3, but that's a different topic than the question at hand. @Barry, thanks for providing the answer to my folder/VPATH problem.